# Obter valor do atributo SRC de uma imagem numa string

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um texto onde existem várias imagens cadastradas e o problema é o seguinte: somente desta *tag* `img` sei o nome do `id` e através deste `id` preciso saber o endereço da imagem que está no `src`.

Exemplo:

```
<img id="img_blog" src="/images/blog/cliente-ideal-voce-sabe-quem-e.jpg" alt="Cliente ideal: Você sabe quem é o do seu negócio?" title="Cliente ideal: Você sabe quem é o do seu negócio?" />
```

Ou seja, faço a busca pelo `id="img_blog"` e ele me retorna o endereço `src="/images/blog/cliente-ideal-voce-sabe-quem-e.jpg"`.

Observação: Aceito solução em JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## JavaScript

Com JavaScript, você pode criar um novo elemento de forma programática, inserir o conteúdo da sua *string* como conteúdo deste elemento e, após, utilizar a função `querySelector` para buscar a imagem desejada e recuperar o valor do atributo `src`. Perceba que o elemento criado existirá só virtualmente, pois o mesmo não é inserido no corpo do documento.

```js
const data = `
  <img src="/images/blog/outra-imagem-A.jpg" />
  <img src="/images/blog/outra-imagem-B.jpg" />
  <img id="img_blog" src="/images/blog/cliente-ideal-voce-sabe-quem-e.jpg" />
  <img src="/images/blog/outra-imagem-C.jpg" />
  <img src="/images/blog/outra-imagem-D.jpg" />
`;

const virtual = document.createElement("div");
virtual.innerHTML = data;

const img = virtual.querySelector("#img_blog");

console.log(img.getAttribute("src"));
```

## PHP

Já, com PHP, você pode utilizar a classe nativa [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.dom.php) para analisar o conteúdo da sua *string* e extrair a informação desejada:

```
<?php

$data = <<<HTML
  <img src="/images/blog/outra-imagem-A.jpg" />
  <img src="/images/blog/outra-imagem-B.jpg" />
  <img id="img_blog" src="/images/blog/cliente-ideal-voce-sabe-quem-e.jpg" />
  <img src="/images/blog/outra-imagem-C.jpg" />
  <img src="/images/blog/outra-imagem-D.jpg" />
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$img = $dom->getElementById("img_blog");

echo $img->getAttribute("src"), PHP_EOL;
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NWD9/0)</sup>

Comment: Prezado Anderson, Agradeço sua atenção pelo script postado pelas modificações necessárias que tive que realizar coube certo em minhas necessidades. Abraços e um bom final de semana...