# Obter valor do atributo SRC de uma imagem numa string II

Tags: php, html

Prezado Anderson, após ter estudado o seu código em PHP e adapta-lo as minhas necessidades. Surgiu uma segunda pergunta estou trabalhando com objetos e não como array, se por acaso existir dois id iguais para imagens diferente? Como converter em array para utilizar um foreach, e ele me mostrar as duas imagens diferentes de um id igual. Espero ter sido claro na minha questão. Abraços,

Comment: Rogarfil, sua pergunta não faz sentido algum da maneira que está. A pergunta deve ser completa por si só, sem depender de qualquer outra informação, então, por favor, edite a pergunta e faça uma eprgunta completa. Lembre-se que o atributo `id` no HTML caracteriza um elemento **único** no documento. Se sua aplicação possui mais de um elemento com o mesmo `id`, então deve ter coisa errada.

Comment: Não me atentei a este fato tão lógico, quanto a pergunta sem sentido algum, peço desculpas e agradeço sua atenção nas minhas elucidações...

Comment: Acho que você pelo menos deveria colocar o link para a questão do Anderson. Eu mesmo, não tenho ideia sobre o que é que você está falando.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250357/132

Comment: Até dá pra colecionar elementos com o mesmo `id`, mas isso foge dos padrões. No caso, teria que puxar pela tag, que torna mais complicado.

Comment: @DvD até fiz um teste no meu servidor com mesmo id e funcionou, porém no repl.it só retornou um src (o primeiro)

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Editei meu comentário acima. Teria que ignorar a id e puxar pelo nome da tag ou qualquer outra coisa em comum.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Ou seja, a id não serviria pra nada, logo, não faz sentido usar mesma id.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Isso é fácil. Basta puxar pelo nome da tag.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Ainda mais se os elementos estiverem dentro de um container, tipo: `<div id="aba"><span id="1"></span><span id="1"></span></div>`. Basta pegar cada span dentro da div com id aba.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Ixi, não deu nada nesse link.

Comment: @DvD esqueci de salvar  https://repl.it/NYCi

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Normal. Vc deu um loop pela tagname e pegou apenas os que tinham o id especificado.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Como eu disse, funciona, mas foge dos padrões rs.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Se puxar pelo id, sempre o primeiro é o válido, os outros são ignorados.

Comment: @DvD entendi, entãose o Rogarfil quiser pode usar o id, bastando alterar para `if(strstr($image->getAttribute('id'),'img_blog')==true){` Fui, boa noite!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quanto ao uso de ids iguais tenha em mente que as ids são uma forma de identificar um elemento, e devem ser ÚNICAS para cada elemento, portanto utilize **classes** que são uma forma de identificar um grupo de elementos.

```
$htmlImagens =<<<DEMO
  <img src="/images/blog/outra-imagem-A.jpg" />
  <img class="img_blog" src="/images/blog/outra-imagem-B.jpg" />
  <img class="img_blog" src="/images/blog/cliente-ideal-voce-sabe-quem-e.jpg" />
  <img src="/images/blog/outra-imagem-C.jpg" />
  <img src="/images/blog/outra-imagem-D.jpg" />
DEMO;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($htmlImagens);
//fazemos um loop procurando por ocorrências da Tag “img”
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image) {
    //destacamos somente aquelas com classe "img_blog"
    if(strstr($image->getAttribute('class'),'img_blog')==true){
       // o array com os src das tags img cuja classe é "img_blog"
       $images[] = $image->getAttribute('src');
    }
}
print_r($images);
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/NWD9/2)

**Bibliografia**

[DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php)

[foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)

[strstr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strstr.php)

Comment: Agora entendi. Bem bacana.

Comment: @DvD, foi o que entendi, ele quer um array dos src das imagens com determinados ids,iguais, só que mudei para classe